# Store array of classes in a list

Tags: c#

I have a class as below,

```
class EUInput
{
    public EUInput()
    {
         RtID = 0;
    }

    public int RtID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store this class with different RtID values in a list. I tried as below,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   EUInput clsEUInput = new EUInput();

   List list = new List();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       clsEUInput.RtID = i;
       list.Add(clsEUInput); 
   }

   foreach (EUInput obj in list)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(obj.RtID.ToString()); 
   }

   Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

I am getting an output as
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4

But I need an outupt as
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `EUInput` to be a `struct` (and keep your `Main` method as it is):

```
public struct EUInput
{
  public int RtID;
}
```

A `struct` is a value type (a `class` is a reference type), so when you add it to a list, you basically add a "copy" of the whole `struct`ure (and not just a reference). So when you keep changing the `RtID` in the loop, you still change that one object you created, but the objects in the list won't be affected.

Either your boss is playing a trick on you, i.e. want's to test your knowledge about value types and reference types, or he doesn't know about the difference between them himself...

Comment: The question remains: *why* doesn't your boss accept any of the solutions provided so far? What are his reasons? If it's not a trick or a test, then I truly belive he has no idea how objects in .Net work. The task is simply impossible to do without explicitly or implicitly creating new objects. Even with this `struct` "solution" there would be new objects created. With a `class`, you create *one* object and then just pass around references to that object. So your list would contain five references to one single object and `clsEUInput` in your `Main` also references that one single object.

Comment: And if you change the object through any of the six references, then you will still see the changes through any of the other references. Because once again, they all lead to the exact same object.

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the declaration of clsEUInput *inside* the for loop. Right now, there is only one EUInput object and you're adding the same object to the list multiple times.

```
List list = new List();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    EUInput clsEUInput = new EUInput();
    clsEUInput.RtID = i;
    list.Add(clsEUInput); 
}
```

Comment: I did this already. My boss not accepting to create instance in that for loop every time. any other solution?

Comment: Yes, but then you have to ditch `EUInput` altogether. Just create a `List<int>` and inside the for loop, add `i` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

you Need new instances to the class
or the complete list will hold references to the one instance

```
private class EUInput
{
    public EUInput()
    {
        RtID = 0;
    }

    public int RtID { get; set; }
}

//I want to store this class with different RtID values in a list. I tried as below,
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<EUInput> list = new List<EUInput>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        EUInput clsEUInput = new EUInput();
        clsEUInput.RtID = i;
        list.Add(clsEUInput);
    }

    foreach (EUInput obj in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.RtID.ToString());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I told that to my boss, he is not accepting it and asking any other solution?

Comment: like this ? 
    private class EUInput
    {
        public EUInput(int size)
        {
            this.RtIDs = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                this.RtIDs.Add(i);
        }

        public List<int> RtIDs { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EUInput ei = new EUInput(5);

        foreach (int i in ei.RtIDs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }